# My stored procedure works fine when I test it but returns nothing PDO

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, pdo

```
Set @req =CONCAT('Select name, id',Ptype,' from ',Ptype);
IF Ptype = "Country" THEN
    SET @req = CONCAT(@req,' where idContinent=',Psurtypeid);
ELSEIF Ptype="State" THEN
    SET @req = CONCAT(@req,' where idCountry=',Psurtypeid);
ELSEIF Ptype="Area" THEN
    SET @req = CONCAT(@req,' where idState=',Psurtypeid);
END IF;
PREPARE stmt FROM @req;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

And my php code

```
$strReq = "Call AfficherLocationList('$subtype'," . $result["id"] . ")";
    $req = $bd->prepare($strReq);
    $req->execute();
    $arrayOptions = $req->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

When I debug and get the resulting query it looks like this `CALL AfficherLocationList('State',1)` and it works fine both in Mysql Workbench and Php Myadmin
but returns an empty array in my code...

Comment: Add `$bd->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` right after the connection is opened, if you're not already doing so, see if it yields anything. Plus, that `$bd` variable; I've seen cases before where it was mixed up and should have been `$db`. Make sure that is in fact the correct variable, and not a typo.

Comment: Thx for the tip with error display. It helped me out :) and the $bd variable is just french for $db

Comment: You're welcome. Yeah, I had a feeling about the `bd`, which I think stands for "base de données" ;-)